# Enabling macros in a word file

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

How do we enable macros in a MS Word document. Assume i have a document with many questions and answer choices. I am not able to see the correct answers. I found a suggestion like enable macros in WORD and you must be able to see the correct answers.

Comment: If Yonathan Klijnsma his answer does not help: What version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change some security settings. Take look here
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-documents-HA010031071.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If other solutions about security settings and enabling macros didn't work for you, you may check this answer, how to enable macros again.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443389/the-macros-in-this-project-have-been-disabled/52578241#52578241